# Cardio Machines which let me get my data

Tags: cardio, gym, exercise-equipment

I am looking for a gym Cardio Machines (brands) which will let me get data representing what I have done.

It should be possible to view it with hearth rate data in a meaningful way, preferably in a major fitness "app".  (I can get hearth rate data seperately)

I am actually looking for a gym, but I think it is easier to  know first about the machines.

Can also be nice to have built in fitness tests, or the possibility to have the heart rate direct the exercise. 
(Europe)

Comment: Have you considered getting a Fitbit or similar device? It measures your heart rate, counts your steps, and calculates your calorie expenditure. At that point, you don't really need the treadmill itself to feed you the data.

Comment: My main purpose is to look at hearth rate for a given program over time.  I also think knowing exactly what I did must be useful for many purposes.

Comment: Then I *definitely* suggest Fitbit or similar. You can tell it that you're getting on/off the treadmill, and it records it as a workout. You can then go back and look at that time period in the app or on the website, and see what your heartrate was during the workout, how many steps you took, and how many calories burned.

Comment: You cant record more?  If I cant get it from the machine, I need an app where I can easily  register all settings from 3-6 stations.  (Also I have a proper hearth rate monitor which detects  motion, so I wont buy a BitFit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Concept2](http://www.concept2.com) makes three types of cardio machines: indoor rower, BikeErg, and SkiErg.  All three use a computerized monitor (PM3, PM4, or PM5, depending on age of machine) that supports connecting a heart rate monitor *and* a mobile app to it.  As you work out, the machine sends detailed data (per stroke) to the mobile app, then the app syncs the workouts to the [Concept2 Online Log](http://log.concept2.com).  More information on this from Concept2: https://www.concept2.com/indoor-rowers/motivation/online-logbook-ranking

Once synced to the Online Log, you can view a neat graph of your performance vs. heart rate.  Here's one of my workouts for an example: https://log.concept2.com/profile/1145484/log/39783999.

If the built-in functionality is not enough, you can export this data in one of several formats and do your own processing on it.

Concept2 claims that their machines are self-calibrating so that your performance on any machine is directly comparable to any other machine.  (With the caveat that the machines are in good condition, properly lubricated, etc.)